# How does form.reset() work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that `form.reset()` will reset all form fields to their default values, but how does that work?

Is it the browser's DOM implementation? i.e. the browser knows what were the last values sent from the server in last postback/get and when `reset()` is called the browser resets those values.

Comment: The way I've always understood it is that .reset() will return the fields in the form to the values that the browser first saw when the page was loaded. But you already know that. Not sure how it works. I wonder if there is a way in JS to be able to read what was the first value on page load? That way you could reset individual fields

Comment: @Brady there's the `element.defaultValue` attribute for that

Comment: @Pekka nice, didn't know that. Is that reliably available cross-browser?

Comment: @Pekka - +1 for that little tidbit I didn't yet know ;)

Comment: @seanizer yup, it's defined in DOM level 1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533718(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DOM spec [tells us](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-76767677) that it:

> ...performs the same action as a reset button.

And so off to HTML. According to the [latest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#concept-form-reset) (still a draft!):

> When a form element form is reset, the user agent must fire a simple event named reset, that is cancelable, at form, and then, if that event is not canceled, must invoke the reset algorithm of each resettable element whose form owner is form, and broadcast formchange events from form.
>
> Each resettable element defines its own reset algorithm. Changes made to form controls as part of these algorithms do not count as changes caused by the user (and thus, e.g., do not cause input events to fire).

And the ["reset algorithm" for `input` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element) (for instance) is:

> ...to set the dirty value flag and dirty checkedness flag back to false, set the value of the element to the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or the empty string otherwise, set the checkedness of the element to true if the element has a checked content attribute and false if it does not, empty the list of selected files, and then invoke the value sanitization algorithm, if the type attribute's current state defines one.

So basically, `reset` sets the value of an input to the current value of its "value" *attribute* (`theElement.getAttribute("value")`), which may be different from its current `value` *property* (`theElement.value`). [Live example here.](http://jsbin.com/amuku3)

**Edit**: Oooh, Pekka points us at [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-26091157). Very cool, I'd much rather use that than `getAttribute("value")`. [Revised live example.](http://jsbin.com/amuku3/2)

Answer (score 5):

`reset` will use the values in the current HTML source code. The Browser does not know anything about the last Request in this Request (that would be a huge security breach).

If the form contains these elements:

```
<form action="xyz">
    <input type="text" name="fieldA" />
    <input type="text" name="fieldB" value="Thingy" />
    <input type="reset" value="Click me to undo everything" />
    <input type="button" onclick="this.form.reset()" value="Click me too" />
</form>
```

Both buttons will empty the first field and set the value of the second field to `Thingy`.

Comment: There is no "current HTML source code" once the document has been parsed. There is the result of parsing it (the DOM).

Comment: that's what I meant. your version sounds better though :-)