# How do I reset a checkbox thats checked value is set by php?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have a web form with a bazillion check boxes. If the form is filled out incorrectly, none of the check boxes are reset (as an anti-frustration feature).

Problem is, the reset button doesn't work to uncheck all the boxes if the form has been submitted before. How do I fix this?

`document.getElementById("form").reset()` doesn't work if the form has been submitted beforehand either.

Sample code below:

```
<body>

<script>
function resetData() {
    document.getElementById("deleteContactFlag").checked=false;
    document.getElementById("userAdministrationFlag").checked=false;
}
</script>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteContactFlag" id="deleteContactFlag" <?php if (isset($_POST["deleteContactFlag"])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/> Delete Contacts<br>
    <input name="userAdministrationFlag" type="checkbox" id="userAdministrationFlag" <?php if (isset($_POST["userAdministrationFlag"])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/> User Administration<br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <button type="button" onClick="resetData()">Reset</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("form").reset();` works for me

Comment: =\ I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think `reset` sets all inputs to the initial value. In your case some of those inputs are initially "checked". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125247/how-does-form-reset-work

Comment: Actually, it works, but only if the user has not pressed the submit button yet. After they press it, it no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

The form reset does not clear all the values in the form, but sets the form back to it's initial state, which it had when the page first loaded. (In this initial state some checkboxes are already checked.)

Try resetting all checkboxes manually:

```
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i in inputs)
    if (inputs[i].type=="checkbox") inputs[i].checked=false;
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() { this.checked=false; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Php code outside of the html elements

HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"method="post" id="form">

    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteContactFlag" id="deleteContactFlag" /> Delete Contacts
    <input name="userAdministrationFlag" type="checkbox" id="userAdministrationFlag" /> User Administration

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <button type="button" onClick="resetData()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to check and un-check `checkbox` inputs if you're finding the form reset functionality to be unreliable. (I believe the resetting the form should just set it back to it's initial state on page load which is why you might be having this problem?). Here's an example:

```
function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
{
  var checkboxes = new Array(); 
  checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
      checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
    }
  }
}

<a onclick="javascript:checkAll('form', true);" href="javascript:void();">check all</a>
<a onclick="javascript:checkAll('form', false);" href="javascript:void();">uncheck all</a>
```

Code from here (there's a jQuery example in there too): http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/javascript-function-check-uncheck-checkboxes/