# Unable to reset form input fields (React JS controlled component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is a ReactJS Problem.**

I can't reset multiple input fields of a form.

There is a form in my app that has multiple input fields, I use an `onChange` function to grab the user inputs, then update `this.state` with `setState`, then I copy all the values from `this.state` with a `spread` operator and create a new object storing those copied values. Lastly, I pass the new object into a function for further use (not relevant). My code problem is I can't empty the fields after passing the object into a function. I tried manually resetting the values by clearing the values with `this.setState`, as well as `event.target.reset()`, but both don't work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddFishForm extends Component {
  // Controlled state
  state = {
    name: "",
    price: "",
    status: "available",
    desc: "",
    image: ""
  };

  // Step 1: onChange: Update this.state
  updateFishState = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  // Step 2: onSubmit: Create Fish Object
  createFish = event => {
    // prevent refresh
    event.preventDefault();
    // copy values inside this.state and paste into new fish object
    const fish = {
      name: this.state.name,
      price: parseFloat(this.state.price),
      status: this.state.status,
      desc: this.state.desc,
      image: this.state.image
    };
    // pass new fish object into addFish() in App.js
    this.props.addFish(fish);
    // ! reset form (NOT WORKING) !
    event.currentTarget.reset();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="fish-edit" onSubmit={this.createFish}>
        <input
          name="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
          onChange={this.updateFishState}
        />
        <input
          name="price"
          value={this.state.price}
          type="text"
          placeholder="price"
          onChange={this.updateFishState}
        />
        <select
          name="status"
          //   Value equals to whichever option is selected
          value={this.optionsState}
          onChange={this.updateFishState}
        >
          <option value="available">Fresh!</option>
          <option value="unavailable">Sold Out!</option>
        </select>
        <textarea
          name="desc"
          value={this.state.desc}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter description..."
          onChange={this.updateFishState}
        />
        <input
          name="image"
          value={this.state.image}
          type="text"
          placeholder="image"
          onChange={this.updateFishState}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Fish</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

I expect the form to be cleared with "event.currentTarget.reset();", but the inputs lingers event after submitting the form. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are managing state via your React Component, the best way to reset state is to create a function that sets the values back to an empty string.

The reason why the `form.reset()` function won't work is that React limits they types of form events: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#form-events (Compare to what the reset function does: [How does form.reset() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125247/how-does-form-reset-work)).

We only get `onChange onInput onInvalid onSubmit`

So add something like

```
reset() {
    this.setState({name: "", price: "", status: "available",desc: "",image: ""})
}
```

Call this function after you `addFish`.

Answer (score 4):

That is not how React works. When you create controlled input in React, it's value is controlled by component's state. All you need to remove is `event.currentTarget.reset();` and replace it with a simple `setState` which resets your form values.

```
this.setState({
  name: "",
  price: "",
  status: "available",
  desc: "",
  image: ""
});
```

This will reset the values, and react will re-render empty form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Thanks. It would be cool if you could elaborate more on what you meant by "When you create controlled input in React, it's valued are controlled by component's state"

Comment: Sorry for not being elaborate from the start. Thing is that "controlled" inputs in React are maintaining their own state through `onChange`, which changes value in state. Native `.reset()` function, does not alter values in the component's state. Therefore our input just continues to use existing value from the state.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Stanko.

Comment: okay but now you lose you state values..how can I reset it but keep my state?

Comment: You'll need to create a copy of your state, by doing something like `const stateCopy = { ...this.state };` before resetting the form.

Answer (score 0):

use this setState method to change your state and rerender the component

```
this.setState({
  name: "",
  price: "",
  status: "available",
  desc: "",
  image: ""
})
```

instead of `event.currentTarget.reset();`